# How can I get my Xamarin xaml designer to work?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, designer

I am having an issue in Xamarin, where I can not get my xaml designer to allow any changes.  When I open an xaml file, it will show the code and allow me to click a little icon in the corner that states "design" when I mouse over.  This will load the designer (I am assuming) with the toolbox and such, but nothing in the toolbox can be placed, and I can not click on anything in the layout. [Image of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFdZi.png)

I am using Windows 7, but have also tried this on a coworkers Windows 10 machine. I am using the "Tabbed" template for a Xamarin.Forms app.

Comment: Xamarin does NOT have a drag-and-drop design surface.  It does have a previewer, which is presumably what you are seeing.

Comment: Is there any sort of designer I can use for Xamarin xaml layouts?

Comment: @JohnManfreda check out this thread: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/148725/visual-designer-for-xamarin-forms-blend-or-an-alternative

Basically the are no true/good designers for xamarin forms. If you do something like a Xamarin.Android project you could design the xaml in Android studio but there are obvious cons to that approach such as now making platform specific views.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a feature that "works" for drag and drop, it's just there for reference.

But it could be something that might be in development at Microsoft in the distant future.